# Notify after 2 consecutive task failures on Airflow

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to only notify/email on 2 consecutive task failures - we want a task to retry first if failed, and if the second try failed again, page. We don't want the email to be sent on the first failure, which Airflow's `email_on_failure` would do.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to disable `email_on_retry` option and enable `email_on_failure` in default_Args.

```
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['example@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'retries': 2,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5)
}
```

That will notify you after the task failed again